# Processing.js failing. no lights(), no anti-aliasing, bad frame rate...?

Tags: processing, processing.js

I recently discovered **Processing** and initially it seemed great for my purposes, to wit generating a 3d image and having it respond multifariously to user input.

*Everything* is working great so far when I run the .pde in the processing environment or as a java applet.

but for my purposes i need to run through a browser and without java dependency.
**Processing.js** seemed at a glance like a golden solution to this.

but the sketch just doesn't look very nice in the browser.

### The three main problems are the following:

-lights() doesn't work.  nor does anything lights associated.  e.g. calling directionalLight(...,params,...) disappears the entire result of draw() and calling lights() only darkens the result uniformly.

-smooth() doesn't work either.  I have maximum anti-aliasing set—smooth(8)— but i see no effect over noSmooth().

-the frame rate is generally pretty bad, so that I have a visible refresh line moving around the object... not good.  I'd estimate that frameRate() is capping out at 30ish fps when i embed in html, no visible cap in native Processing environment or java app.

Yet I've seen a lot of beautiful processing.js examples.  I feel like I must be missing something, else this would be working better. Any insight into these problems and their solutions or lack thereof would be tremendously appreciated.  Or perhaps I should just use WebGL?

Since all my .pde code seems good, I wasn't going to post that.
But for just in case here's the html code (which should be trivial) used to embed the sketch with Processing.js.  I am using Processing.js v1.4.8 obtained here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/processing-js/processing-js/v1.4.8/processing.js

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Processing.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <canvas data-processing-sources="example.pde"/></canvas>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: To be clear, example.pde is failing in all the same ways as listed above in Javascript Mode of Processing.

Comment: I am drawing a QUAD_STRIP, other shapes do have properly working lighting in Javascript Mode...? What is going on

Comment: Facing similar issues concerning framerate and aliasing. Did you find any useful trick? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I bailed on processing and started learing WebGL! Getting good results in conjunction with THREE.js

Comment: Haha I just reached the exact same conclusion!